# Outputting Excel rows to a series of text files

Tags: excel, notepad++, vba

Inside Excel, I have a list of article names in column A, and a disclaimer inside column B. Now for each article in column A, I would like to create a text file, were A is the title of the file and B, the disclaimer, is the contents of the file.

Is this possible?

The idea is that I have several hundred of these, and I would like to make this easier on myself.

If Excel is not ideal for this, can anyone suggest an alternative? (possibly Notepad++ has a feature that can help?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Sub Export_Files()
    Dim sExportFolder, sFN
    Dim rArticleName As Range
    Dim rDisclaimer As Range
    Dim oSh As Worksheet
    Dim oFS As Object
    Dim oTxt As Object

    'sExportFolder = path to the folder you want to export to
    'oSh = The sheet where your data is stored
    sExportFolder = "C:\Disclaimers"
    Set oSh = Sheet1

    Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

    For Each rArticleName In oSh.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
        Set rDisclaimer = rArticleName.Offset(, 1)

        'Add .txt to the article name as a file name
        sFN = rArticleName.Value & ".txt"
        Set oTxt = oFS.OpenTextFile(sExportFolder & "\" & sFN, 2, True)
        oTxt.Write rDisclaimer.Value
        oTxt.Close
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: LOL any time Wayne! Glad to help!

Comment: @transistor1 I came across your answer while searching for a way to create text files from my excel data. I have a quick question though, how would I get this to include the content from column B to J for each row in the text file? Currently this only fills the content with content from column B.

Comment: @SteveC. - you can cycle through rows with `For Each rRow In oSh.UsedRange.Rows`, then you can get a reference to cells B:J in that loop with `Set rng = rRow.Range("B1:J1").Cells` -- don't worry that there's a 1 in the cell address... it will choose B:J in the current row.  Finally, you can loop through each cell in B:J, outputting it into the text file with `For Each c In rng`.  It's kind of hard to post a snippet in a comment, so if this doesn't help with what you're looking for, please post a new question.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach using variant arrays for speed, and an alternative  to the `FileSystemObject` given only file creation is needed.

```
    Sub DataDump()

    Dim X
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim StrFolder As String

    StrFolder = "C:\temp"
    X = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X)
    Open StrFolder & "\" & X(lngRow, 1) & ".txt" For Output As #1
    Write #1, X(lngRow, 2)
    Close #1
    Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked great for me - trying to get the code to repeat for each row of data but it is only creating files for row 2. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: @dorje Do you have data in cells below A2?

Comment: Hello brettdj, I am trying to replicate exactly the same thing and I can't get this to work for more than two lines. I work on a mac, so I fixed the path using ":", which worked, but the macro won't run for more than two rows. I'm stuck with a 52 error. Any ideas ?

Comment: Orf, just realized macro stopped because of apostrophes in titles... Thank you very much, it works like a charm on office mac.

Comment: One last question ! Do you have any idea why the macro would stop when the titles are too long ? Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough Rep to comment on other people's post yet so I have to post this as an answer.  The accepted answer by @transistor1 works; however, in Excel 2010 need to change

> `Set oSh = Sheet1`

to `Set oSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("worksheet")`

Where "worksheet" is the name of the worksheet the data is on.