# Extract text from column D to txt files and name files based on content of column C

Tags: vba, excel

Apologies for a noob question but I've been fiddling around with this code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7151963/3672159
and can't seem to get it modified to do the following (very slight modifications of the code above):

1. Take as input a worksheet that is called "Export Data" (rather than "Sheet1" as in the existing code; the space seems to cause problems)
2. Automatically create an empty file for each cell of column D, which should have as its content the value of the respective D cell (same as with the "Disclaimer" data in the code above)
3. Name each file based on the values of the corresponding C cells (so for me it's name=column C, content=column D rather than B and A in the original code).

I've modified the code as follows:

```
Sub ExportFiles()
Dim sExportFolder, sFN
Dim rStoreId As Range
Dim rAbstract As Range
Dim oSh As Worksheet
Dim oFS As Object
Dim oTxt As Object

'sExportFolder = path to the folder you want to export to
'oSh = The sheet where your data is stored
sExportFolder = "my file path\txt"
Set oSh = Export Data

Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

For Each rStoreId In oSh.UsedRange.Columns("D").Cells
    Set rAbstract = rStoreId.Offset(, -1)

    'Add .txt to the article name as a file name
    sFN = rStoreId.Value & ".txt"
    Set oTxt = oFS.OpenTextFile(sExportFolder & "\" & sFN, 2, True)
    oTxt.Write rAbstract.Value
    oTxt.Close
  Next
End Sub
```

The only thing this does (as does the original code) is create one empty unnamed txt file.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Gave -1 because your question is both unclear and not useful to other visitors. What exactly is wrong with your code, what have you tried ? If you have a specific problem you should reword your question. If you want us to help you make this work for you then this is too localized (your question could not possibly help any other user).

Comment: ok - got working amswers tho so can't have been *that* unclear. i said what didn't work, didn't i? sorry i work with words not code in my normal life so asking a question in code rather than words is difficult ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
Sub ExportFiles()
Dim sExportFolder, sFN
Dim rStoreId As Range
Dim rAbstract As Range
Dim oSh As Worksheet
Dim oFS As Object
Dim oTxt As Object

'sExportFolder = path to the folder you want to export to
'oSh = The sheet where your data is stored
sExportFolder = "C:\Users\Rich\Desktop"
Set oSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Export Data")


Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

For Each rStoreId In oSh.Columns("D").Cells

    If IsEmpty(rStoreId.Value) Then
        Exit For
    End If

    Set rAbstract = rStoreId.Offset(, -1)

    'Add .txt to the article name as a file name
    sFN = rStoreId.Value & ".txt"
    Set oTxt = oFS.OpenTextFile(sExportFolder & "\" & sFN, 2, True)
    oTxt.Write rAbstract.Value
    oTxt.Close
  Next
End Sub
```

You need to select the sheet correctly with (Assuming it is within the same workbook as the code)...

```
Set oSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Export Data")
```

And I changed how you were iterating through the range...

```
For Each rStoreId In oSh.Columns("D").Cells

    If IsEmpty(rStoreId.Value) Then
        Exit For
    End If

Next
```

This just goes through column D's cells until it hits an empty one, I couldn't quite get it working using UsedRange and this (more old skool) method works in my tests.

Comment: yay works like a charm once I'd set the oSh to ActiveWorkbook :) Thanks ever so much!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. It writes each value in cells in column D to a text file that is named based on the entry in column C and puts all text files in user specified folder:

```
Sub ExportFiles()
    Dim exportFolder As String
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim stream As TextStream
    Dim cl As Range

    exportFolder = "C:\User\ExportFolder"  //Add you folder path here
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject

        For Each cl In Worksheets("Export Data").UsedRange.Columns("D").Cells
            Set stream = fso.CreateTextFile(filepath & "\" & cl.Offset(0, -1).Value & ".txt", 2, True)
            stream.Write cl.Value
            stream.Close
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I get a "user-defined type not defined" for fso As FileSystemObject - but thanks anyway!

Comment: You need to go to `References` and select `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`