# How to produce a formatted report from LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet?

Tags: report, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I have a very simple LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet with column headers and columns (cell can be multiline), someting like:

```
| id | Prio | Domain | Comment        | ... |
|----|------|--------|----------------|-----|
|  1 |    A | Foo    | Something      |     |
|----|------|--------|----------------|-----|
|  2 |    A | Bar    | Something else |     |
|    |      |        | Possibly on    |     |
|    |      |        | multiple lines |     |
|----|------|--------|----------------|-----|
|  1 |    C | Baz    | Something else |     |
```

I would like to obtain, in a (semi) automated way a *plain text file* containing something like:

```
id:      1
Prio:    A
Domain:  Foo
Comment: Something
...

id:      2
Prio:    A
Domain:  Bar
Comment: Something else
         Possibly on
         multiple lines
...

id:      3
Prio:    C
Domain:  Baz
Comment: Something else
...
```

Is this possible somehow?
I am aware of LO macro capabilities (e.g.: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25092195/create-new-txt-html-file-for-each-row-in-ooo-calc-spreadsheet) ), so the trivial answer is probably "yes", but I never used them so I would need some guidance (I don't even know how to use such a thing).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways this could be done.  One idea is to go to `File -> Save As` and save as type CSV.  In the filter settings, check `Quote all text cells` to make it easier to handle newlines.

Then write a script that uses the [python csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params), for example:

```py
import csv
with open('Untitled 1.csv') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel',)
    for row in spamreader:
        print("row: ", end="")
        print(', '.join(row))
```

To avoid the `Save As` step, you could write a macro instead.  It might be easier to write it in [python](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python) rather than [Basic](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php), because file handling and string manipulation can be difficult in Basic.