# Adapt Excel VBA code for Mac OSX: Outputting Excel rows to a series of text files (for topic modeling)

Tags: excel, vba, macos, topic-modeling

I'm doing my first bit of topic modeling, and I'm at the stage of generating separate text files out of every row in a spreadsheet with a macro (as explained here: http://www.themacroscope.org/?page_id=418). The code referred to on that page isn't quite what I need to do, so I'm using this code: [Outputting Excel rows to a series of text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149539/outputting-excel-rows-to-a-series-of-text-files)

It is supposed to make a new text file for every row, using Column A for the filename and Column B for the content.

```
Sub Export_Files()
    Dim sExportFolder, sFN
    Dim rArticleName As Range
    Dim rDisclaimer As Range
    Dim oSh As Worksheet
    Dim oFS As Object
    Dim oTxt As Object

    'sExportFolder = path to the folder you want to export to
    'oSh = The sheet where your data is stored
    sExportFolder = "C:\Disclaimers"
    Set oSh = Sheet1

    Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

    For Each rArticleName In oSh.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
        Set rDisclaimer = rArticleName.Offset(, 1)

        'Add .txt to the article name as a file name
        sFN = rArticleName.Value & ".txt"
        Set oTxt = oFS.OpenTextFile(sExportFolder & "\" & sFN, 2, True)
        oTxt.Write rDisclaimer.Value
        oTxt.Close
    Next
End Sub
```

However, it gives me this error message:

```
Run-time error '429':

ActiveX component can't create object.
```

Which turns out to be due to my being on a Mac. When I click on the Debug button, it highlights this line in yellow:

```
Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
```

Is there a way to tweak this line so it works on a Mac? I'm using Excel 2011 with VBA 14.0 if that makes a difference.

Comment: If this was Windows, I would have avoided the need for a `FileSystemObject` by using `Open sExportFolder & Application.PathSeparator & rArticleName.Value & ".txt" For Output As #1` `Print #1, rDisclaimer.Value` `Close #1`, but I don't know whether that will work on a Mac.

Comment: I replaced "Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")" with that line. It gives me this error:

Compile error:
Syntax error.

What do I do? And is there a way to get carriage returns on these comments?

Comment: I'll post the suggestion as an "answer" so you can see where the line breaks are and so you can put it in the right spot.

Answer (score 1):

If this was a Windows PC, the following would allow you to avoid the need for a `FileSystemObject`:

```
Sub Export_Files()
    Dim sExportFolder As String
    Dim rArticleName As Range
    Dim rDisclaimer As Range
    Dim oSh As Worksheet

    'sExportFolder = path to the folder you want to export to
    'oSh = The sheet where your data is stored
    sExportFolder = "C:\Disclaimers"
    Set oSh = Sheet1

    For Each rArticleName In oSh.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
        Set rDisclaimer = rArticleName.Offset(, 1)
        Open sExportFolder & Application.PathSeparator & rArticleName.Value & ".txt" For Output As #1
        Print #1, rDisclaimer.Value
        Close #1    
    Next
End Sub
```

I do not know whether this works on a Mac.

Comment: It says:

Run-time error:

Path not found.

I'm copying the path to my folder (/Users/[myusername]/Desktop/test/text_files) and pasting it over "C:\Disclaimers". That should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: @RaphaelAizanSasayama I've never used a Mac so I'm not sure whether that path will work or not.  (I **thought** Macs used `:` as the path separator, but I have no easy way of telling.)  Maybe insert a line saying `MsgBox ThisWorkbook.FullName` and see what it says the path is to the current workbook - that should then give you some idea of how a path should be structured.